# Upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 22.04LTS with unchaned packages

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I have a client that has Ubuntu 18.04LTS and he wants to upgrade to 22.04LTS.
For the app server everything worked like a charm, but for the db when i upgraded to 20.04LTS i got this :

```
No candidate ver:  libapache2-mod-php7.2
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.4.0-1032-azure
No candidate ver:  linux-image-5.4.0-1095-azure
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.4.0-1032-azure
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-5.4.0-1095-azure
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1032-azure
No candidate ver:  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1095-azure
No candidate ver:  mysql-server-5.7
No candidate ver:  python
```

and it aborded.

But the `lsb_release -a` reports 20.04LTS

How can I ensure that it indeed upgraded?
As you can see there in a mysql db 5.7 that must stay.

Comment: Have you tried the usual post-upgrade steps of (sudo) `apt update` `dpkg --configure -a`, `apt install -f`, `apt install linux-image-generic mysql-server`, `apt remove` all of the no candidate packages, `apt install -f`, `apt upgrade`, `apt full-upgrade`?

Comment: The request was that the mysql stayed the same version and I am not sure about what to do with these azure modules.

Comment: This is not possible with the mysql server available in the default Ubuntu repositories. 5.6 is not available for *any* supported Ubuntu version. You will need to (neither recommended nor secure) install a third-party PPA.